# Make review title field required - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is the code I am using to add the title on woocommerce review form :

```
function add_review_title_field_on_comment_form() {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-title uk-margin-top"><label for="title">' . __( 'Review Headline', 'text-domain' ) . '</label><input class="uk-input uk-width-large uk-display-block" type="text" name="title" id="title"/></p>';
}
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'add_review_title_field_on_comment_form' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'add_review_title_field_on_comment_form' );

add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_review_title_field' );
function save_comment_review_title_field( $comment_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['title'] ) )
      update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', esc_attr( $_POST['title'] ) );
}

function get_review_title( $id ) {
    $val = get_comment_meta( $id, "title", true );
    $title = $val ? '<strong class="review-title" style="font-size:16px;">' . $val . '</strong>' : '';
    return $title;
}
```

Due to this code, I can able to add headline filed for review form but it's not required please check

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to make this field required please check the screenshot, I know what to do to make any field required but it's coming as a functions to functions.php that's the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want html related required attribute for basic validation using html
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: yes i have added required as well but its not working

Comment: This answer should be more help.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244151/how-to-make-custom-comment-fields-required

Comment: Do you want server side validation or client side?

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj Hmm It's good.

Answer (score 1):

Html5 has default `required` validation so add, check below code for this.

```
 function add_review_title_field_on_comment_form() {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-title uk-margin-top"><label for="title">' . __( 'Review Headline', 'text-domain' ) . '</label><input class="uk-input uk-width-large uk-display-block" type="text" name="title" id="title" required/></p>';

 }
```

And for server side add code in your function , for that check below code.

```
function save_comment_review_title_field( $comment_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['title'] ) && ! empty($_POST[ 'title' ]))
          update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', esc_attr( $_POST['title'] ) );
      else
         wp_die( __('Please enter a valid title, its required.') );
 }
```

Hope this will help you.